# onesignal handle notification when application closed

Tags: android, xamarin.android, onesignal

I am using Onesignal for handlling push notification in android what is the best solution to handle messages when application is closed in xamarin.android

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {......
               OneSignal.Current.StartInit("ONE_SIGNAL_CODE")
                  .HandleNotificationReceived(Static.HandleNotificationReceived)
                    .InFocusDisplaying(OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                    .EndInit();
           }

   public static void HandleNotificationReceived(OSNotification notification)
        {
          Android.Util.Log.Info(tag, "Handle Notification Received");
        }
```

this method not called when application is closed work fine when application is on background or foreground